MS Store .exe app not showing in Updates section
I have published a .exe (built using WPF framework) to Microsoft Store. The exe is generated using Advanced Installer. The app got approved and installed properly from the store. But when I pushed an update to the app, the app is not visible under MS Store -> Library -> Get Updates section.
As per their docs, I have submtted the versioned url while submitting the build and incremented the version in the URL while submitting the update.
ex: https://example.com/app/1.1/My-App.exe
Please point me if I am doing anything wrong here. Also, is the update is visible only when the app is submitted as .MSIX pacakge / built using Store suggested framework?
Thank You
